# I need unique file path to call from Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When I start my game activity, it needs to load three file paths: users/uid/character selected, 
rooms/roomID/chatLog, 
rooms/roomID/userLog

roomID, uid, and character selected are unique to the user and user input gathered from the menu activity which is always created and will contain this information before the game activity. Is it possible, and if so, how?

As far as I know, I can only load the roots of these paths (rooms/ and users/), forcing me to program a way to sift through this information, which would take forever and be a drain on batteries and a waste of time.

Comment: I don't think I understand what the problem is here.  What do you mean by "I can only load rooms/ and users/"?

Comment: I clarified it.

Comment: Still not clear to me.  What is preventing you from making the queries for the data you need?

Comment: The steps I need to take in the file path are unique to the user, but the reference doesn't seem to be capable of using them

Comment: Without seeing code, I have no idea what you're running in to.  If you can build a path to it, you can query it. That's never a problem.

Comment: That is the problem. I can't build the path, because it needs variables to build, but I need to hard code it. I have no code to give you.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something that can't be done. If you can't build a specific path, then you can't query it.